# Create and pass random values to Pandas dataframes with hard bounds

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to simulate a pandas dataframe, using random values, with a combination of hard upper/lower values. I am using np.random.normal, as the original data is fairly normally distributed.

The code I am using to create the dataframe is:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Temp": np.random.normal(6.809892, 2.975827,93),
    "Sun": np.random.normal(1.615054,2.053996,93),
    "Rel Hum": np.random.normal(87.153118,5.529958,93)
})
```

In the above example, I would like there to be a hard lower and upper bound for all three values. For example, Rel. Hum. could not go below 0, or above 100. *Edit: all three values would not have the same bounds, either upper or lower. Temp can go negative, while sun would be bounded at 0, and 24)*

How can I force these values, while creating a relatively normally distribution, and passing them to the dataframe at the same time?

Comment: You could [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) it after generating the numbers, but then you'll have tiny spikes at the edges.

Comment: You can clip the endpoints, or re-draw from that distribution until you get a point within bounds. Either way it wont be truly normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit : Note that this samples from a truncated normal for the given parameters and will most likely not be truly normally distributed, sorry for the confusion.

Use scipy [truncated normal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html) defined as :

"The standard form of this distribution is a standard normal truncated to the range [a, b]"

```
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
low_bound = 0
upper_bound = 100
mean = 8
std = 2
a, b = (low_bound - mean) / std, (upper_bound - mean) / std
n_samples = 1000

samples = truncnorm.rvs(a = a, b = b,
                        loc = mean, scale = std,
                        size = n_samples)
```

Thanks to [ALollz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4333359/alollz) for the corrections !

Comment: How would I then pass these values into the pandas dataframe?

Comment: @Clauric  ``pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : samples})``

Comment: @ALollz Yeah, it doesn't look 'normal' but it does sample from a truncated normal ; I'm actually not sure what OP meant as if they want to sample from a truncated normal or clipping from a normal. Both cases won't end up being normal, highly depending on the parameters but I agree my answer will likely be confusing.

Comment: @NaturalFrequency: Thank you. this worked perfectly

Comment: @Clauric, please do note the edit and the fact that your samples won't be normally distributed, if that's what you're going for then clipping is better.

Answer (score 2):

Try [clip()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) function to bound the values, example:

```
>>> df[df['Rel Hum']>100].head()
        Temp       Sun     Rel Hum
32  4.734005  4.102939  100.064077
Name: Rel Hum, Length: 93, dtype: float64
>>> df[df['Rel Hum']>100].head()
        Temp       Sun     Rel Hum
32  4.734005  4.102939  100.064077
>>> df['Rel Hum'].clip(0, 100, inplace=True) # assigns values outside boundary to 0 and 100 
>>> df.head()
       Temp       Sun    Rel Hum
0  9.714943  6.255931  93.105135
1  0.551001  3.063972  85.923184
2  7.780588  3.580514  79.124139
3  3.766066  3.684801  84.543149
4  8.541507 -3.066196  83.598925
>>> df[df['Rel Hum']>100].head()
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Temp, Sun, Rel Hum]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do a `clip`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Temp": np.random.normal(6.809892, 2.975827,93),
    "Sun": np.random.normal(1.615054,2.053996,93),
    "Rel Hum": np.random.normal(87.153118,5.529958,93)
}).clip(0,100)
```

And plot:

```
df.plot.density(subplots=True);
```

gives:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can `clip`, though this leaves you with a spike at the edges:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 10**5
df = pd.DataFrame({"Rel Hum": np.random.normal(87.153118,5.529958, N)})

df['Rel Hum'].clip(lower=0, upper=100).plot(kind='hist', bins=np.arange(60,101,1))
```

[image]

---

If you want to avoid that spike redraw out of bounds points until everything is within bounds:

```
while not df['Rel Hum'].between(0, 100).all():
    m = ~df['Rel Hum'].between(0, 100)
    df.loc[m, 'Rel Hum'] = np.random.normal(87.153118, 5.529958, m.sum())

df['Rel Hum'].plot(kind='hist', bins=np.arange(60,101,1))
```

[image]